# Caliburn.Micro Drag & Drop of a File in a WPF

Tags: wpf, file, drag-and-drop, caliburn.micro

I Have create and desktop application with Caliburn.Micro (2.0.1) and now I need to add a drag&drop behavior, the user will drag a file from the Windows Explorer and I need to get the path of it, however I´m searching for 2 days now and I don´t found any example or explanation of how to add a Drag&Drop behavior for the Caliburn.Micro. I found a question about it ([Drag and Drop Files into WPF with Caliburn Micro Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078838/drag-and-drop-files-into-wpf-with-caliburn-micro-framework)) but that don´t workout. I have tried a lot of different maners but now sucess, my list try was this:

```
<TextBox Name="Relatorio"
         Width="612" Margin="1" 
         AllowDrop="True"
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event Drop] = [Action DropQ($eventArgs)];
                             [Event DragOver] = [Action DragQ($eventArgs)]">
```

Any suggestions at all?

Answer (score 5):

Solution,

```
 <TextBox Name="Relatorio"
 Width="612" Margin="1" 
 AllowDrop="True" 
 cal:Message.Attach="[Event Drop] = [Action FileDropped($eventArgs)];
          [Event PreviewDragOver] = [Action FilePreviewDragEnter($eventArgs)]"/>


    public void FilePreviewDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public void FileDropped(DragEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Sorry the problem persists, the events aren't getting fired.

Comment: This solution works fine, Please create a sample project and upload for me.

Comment: Just tested this solution and both methods were hit in the debugger when a file was dragged and dropped on the TextBox.

Comment: it´s possible to send a private msg? I can send a project for test. my twitter @GLMsharp